# Running Nginx Webserver with Latest Changes

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I have configured my nginx webserver according to this documentation http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html 
So now, I pull the latest code from my github account and restarted my server and its not showing the latest changes. 
And I am using Ubuntu as my OS

I want it to show the latest code changes.

Important info:
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals

I used this command to run my sever

After performing all these steps mentioned below in comments,nothing happens. It doesn't run with the latest changes. What I am missing to make my website run with latest code which i am pulling on my server from my github account.

Comment: Make sure to restart uwsgi process if you are talking about nginx server.

Comment: Although there may be a better way, for things like static files to be updated, I always restart my server with `sudo reboot now`, and then all changes should take effect when the server comes back up. That has been the only reliable method for me personally.

Comment: @elethan You don't have to reboot your entire server (that's actually bad practise). Instead, use `python manage.py collectstatic` to update static files, and then restart your WSGI (uWSGI, Gunicorn, or whatever you're using) and all should be well. Be sure to clear your cache if you have one.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence thanks, I will try this next time, but in the past there have been times when running `collectstatic`, restarting `nginx`, and restarting `gunicorn` were not enough. Also, what makes rebooting the server a bad practice (I assumed it was, but I would like to know why - other than the obvious fact that your site will go down for a few seconds.)

Comment: I see... When I first started, I too had issues and then I remembered that I had Django compressing static files, so I had to run `python manage.py compress --force` after the `collectstatic` and then restart `gunicorn`. Yeah, that's pretty much the reason. Especially if it's a high-volume site with ecommerce. Not just that, if you're running other apps from the same server (eg streaming or APIs that need to be up) then it's not good. If you only have your website, and uptime isn't an issue, then I suppose it's acceptable.

Comment: After rebooting server and restarting uwsgi, nothing happens. It still doesn't show the latest changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, It was a very silly mistake. Restarting UWSGI and Nginx works perfectly fine :)